# Issue in the calculator

Tags: python

```
d = dict([(1,'Addition'),
          (2,'Substraction'),
          (3,'Multiplication'),
          (4,'Division(Integer)'),
          (5,'Division(Float)'),
          (6, 'Exponent')])
print(d)

n =int (input("Enter the Number whose operation u wanna perform :"))
a =int (input("Enter First Number :"))
b =int (input("Enter Second Number :"))
if n == 1:
    if 56 in a and 9 in b:
        print(77)
    else:
        print(a + b)
elif n==2:
     print(a - b)
elif n == 3:
    if 45 in a and 3 in b:
        print(555)
    else:
        print(a*b)
elif n == 4:
    print(a//b)
elif n == 5:
    if 56 in a and 6 in b:
        print(4)
    else:
        print(a/b)
elif n == 6:
    print(a**b)
```

Everything is fine but when I enter the number which is assigned like in addition, if I enter 56 and 9 in `a` and `b` respectively, I am getting this error:

```
 if 56 in a and 9 in b:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: What do you think `56 in a` is supposed to mean?

Comment: why no just return  print(a + b)

Comment: Do you mean a == 56 and b == 9?

Comment: also " in 'a' " is like performing to search if 56 in array 'a', so i think you should not use like this.

Comment: @mkrieger1 just wanna check whether the number is their or not , but i get that instead i should use '==' will be more beneficial.

Comment: @susil95 yes i got you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterable means something that can be looped over - to go through one thing at a time until you reach the end. So you can ask if a list of items contains something by looking `in` the list for that item - which iterates until it's found.

Since you are asking if 56 is `in` `a` and it's not a list of items you've told Python to do something that doesn't make sense and it produces that error explaining why.

Now the use of `==` meaning *is equal to* is the correct answer as per other comments - however you could also have put `a` in a list with `[a]` - now `in` would work and `==` wouldn't since a list of one item `a` is not the same as `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You receive integers from input so you must compare using '==' instead of 'in'

```
if n == 1:
if 56 == a and 9 == b:
    print(77)
else:
    print(a + b)
```